# retrict users from downloading document

Tags: document, library

Is it possible to allow user to checkout a document from a library for editing, but restrict downloading their ability to download document? (SP 2010)

Comment: Can you explain what is your end goal? Maybe someone would be able help out! Otherwise, as Aziz has already answered, it is a very difficult restriction to impose.

Comment: Allow users to check out a document , but not able to download it to their personal folder in the shared drive.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Office Web Apps and want users to only be able to edit docs only there, and not in client Office applications, then check [this](http://www.sharepoint4arabs.com/mohamedyehia/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=60). Strategy here is to define custom SPRole (permissions set) or use built-in `View Only` and force it.

If there are no Office Web Apps, then editing any document with desktop Office application involves downloading it first (to browser cache or drafts folders). So preventing download and allowing clients is not possible at the same time.

Document in Word could be **saved-as** to some local location as soon as it's opened - that is equivalent to downloading it, right?

Comment: Or check a solution from JoelHill4149 at https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/190437, but I'm not sure about it